# After got image link in JSON, how to make the image appear on the web-browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rest, fetch

I'm learning to code for three months, and recently I learned some of the basic backend (database & server) and react. Now I'm trying to create a web app, which displays one random picture on a web-browser using the pixabay API, and another feature of the app I'm thinking is I can filter the picture displayed depends on the theme. (since each picture has tags key, like "tags": "landscape, summer, beach", I will create an input field that allows a user to type what kind of picture they want to get)

Now I was successfully got JSON data for pictures and logged them on the console, but I'm kind of confused about what to do next. I'm guessing I need to make two functions in order to select one picture & filter the response (?). What do you think?

So, I want some advice from you all. These are some of the files I currently have.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Image from "./components/Image";
import Button from "./components/Button";

function App() {
  function getPictures() {
    const url =
      "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=[I put my key here & deleted for now]";
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        return console.log(json);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Image />
      <Button getPictures={getPictures} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

another file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Button = (props) => {
  const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);
  function start() {
    setHasStarted(true);
  }

  return (
    <div className="button-area">
      <div className="slideShowBtn btn">
        {hasStarted && <button>Go back</button>}
        {hasStarted && <button>Next picture</button>}
      </div>

      <div className="startBtn btn">
        {!hasStarted && (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              startCCC();
              props.getPictures();
            }}
          >
            Start
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably include what you have in your `Image` component as well, but it appears that what you are trying to do is to have the `Image` component display an image and when you push the button the image changes.  So what you need is to store the image url in some state and then pass that to the display component.

Something like:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
function App() {
  const [ imageUrl, setImageUrl ] = useState( null );
  const getPicture = useCallback( () => {
    const url = 'https://pixabay.com/api/?key=...';
    fetch( url ).then( data => {
      // I don't know what the API response looks like, this is just an example...
      const url = data.json().image.url;
      if ( url ) setImageUrl( url );
    } );
  }, [ setImageUrl ] );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Image url={imageUrl} />
      <Button getPictures={getPictures} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! now I was able to list them on browser!